# Having problems with accessing files on a mapped network drive, using pywin32 client

Tags: directory, python-3.6, docx, pywin32

I am currently using the following code to open up a word document (and then save it but that is irrelevant to opening the file at the moment):

```
    word=win32.Dispatch('Word.Application')
    try:                      
    doc = word.Documents.Open('S:\problem\file.docx')
    except Exception as e:
    print(e)

    (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Sorry, we 
    couldn’t find your file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or 
    deleted?\r (S:\\problem\\file.docx)', 
    'wdmain11.chm', 24654, -2146823114), None)
```

The "problem" directory is the only directory it seems the win32 client is not able to recognize. I have renamed it several times to even single letters to see if the naming was the problem for some reason, but that does not seem to be the problem.

The file path is also recognized by the docx function- docx.Document and it is able to read the files in the directory. Here is the same code and results for the docx snippet:

```
    Document('S://problem/file.docx')
    <docx.document.Document at 0x83d3c18>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Python* strings, *bkslash* (***"\"***) is one of the characters with a special meaning: it's used to create *escape sequences* (special *char*s) together with the char that follows it (this comes from *C*). Here's what [[Python 3]: String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) states:

> The backslash (`\`) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

In your string, you have *"\p"* (which is *OK*) and *"\f"* which is interpreted as a **single** *char* (*form feed - new page*), making your path invalid.

In order to fix this, either:

- Escape (double) any *"\"* in the string (well, this is just a precaution measure since you only have to escape the ones that produce an escape sequence - in our example, *"\p"* is perfectly fine), except the ones that you **want** to produce an escape sequence: *'S:\problem\file.docx'*
- Make the string *raw*, by prepending it with the **r** marker (note that if the string ends with a *"\"*, that should still be escaped, otherwise it will escape the string ending marker (***'*** or ***"***) that comes after it, yielding *SyntaxError*): *r'S:\problem\file.docx'*

As a general rule, in order to ensure that strings are what you think they are, either:

- Check their length: if it's smaller than the number of chars you see (in the code), it means that there is at least one escape sequence
- Use *repr*

**Example**:

> ```py
> >>> import sys
> >>> sys.version
> '3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
> >>>
> >>> s0 = 'S:\problem\file.docx'
> >>> s1 = 'S:\\problem\\file.docx'
> >>> s2 = r'S:\problem\file.docx'
> >>>
> >>> len(s0), len(s1), len(s2)
> (19, 20, 20)
> >>>
> >>> s0 == s1, s1 == s2
> (False, True)
> >>>
> >>> repr(s0), repr(s1), repr(s2)
> ("'S:\\\\problem\\x0cile.docx'", "'S:\\\\problem\\\\file.docx'", "'S:\\\\problem\\\\file.docx'")
> ```

Comment: Ah can not believe I did not realize this! Thank you!
I was playing around with the separator and using forward slashes as well, and for some reason after trying it with a forward slash (as well as r)  today it worked, haha thanks though!

Comment: I have suspicion that this was not actually the problem though, because  here is the one variation of the actual directory I used (with some things changed) that was not working yesterday, but after I named and then renamed the directories back, it is working now :

'S://Qualitative/Restricted/CTE/Docs/12_1_2017/CTE PAF Table 3.doc'

which was using forward slashes, and can't have any special characters in it as its working currently without any changes

Comment: I didn't get the last comment. Is it working? It should with forward slashes (although some apps might not support them).

Comment: Yes it's working! Except I feel the problem was irrelevant of the slashes, as I had tried that variation of the file path and it did not work earlier, but is now working-

I assume this change in behavior may be related to me naming and renaming the problem directory (in this case it is the 12_1_2017 directory) but can't really zero in what problem actually was.